# Error message "FileNotFoundException" is showing if I run the runnable .jar file from command line

Tags: selenium

[Error message is showing when I run the created runnable .jar file from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIq3x.png)

1. Error message "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Files\Learners_login_sheet_1.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)" is showing when I run the runnable .jar file from the Command line.
2. Same code is working fine if I run the same code from the Eclipse "run as TestNG".

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.stream.Collectors;
   import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

   public class Utility
   {
   public static ArrayList<String[]> getDataFromExcel()
   {
   ArrayList<String[]> myData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   Workbook dataWorkbook = null;
   try
   {

   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Files/Learners_login_sheet_1.xlsx"));
   String fileName="Learners_login_sheet_1.xlsx";
   String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
   if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx"))
   {
   dataWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
   }
   else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls"))
   {
   dataWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
   }
   }
   catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   String sheetName="Learner_details";
   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet signupSheet = dataWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
   int rowCount = signupSheet.getLastRowNum()-signupSheet.getFirstRowNum();
   for(int rowNum=2; rowNum <=rowCount; rowNum++ )
   {
   Row row=signupSheet.getRow(rowNum);
   String Email=row.getCell(0).toString();
   String Password=row.getCell(1).toString();
   String obj[]={Email, Password};
   myData.add(obj);
   }
   return myData;
   }
   }

Comment: Looks like `Files/Learners_login_sheet_1.xlsx` is a relative path, so it must be relative to where you are running from.

Comment: you should bundle as a resource and then extract it to a known location... something like :  System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"...